# WooCommerce: Don't display Shipping Addreess on virtual products in Apple, Google or Amazon Pay

Tags: woocommerce, stripe-payments, applepay, google-pay, amazon-pay

Have a client with a small store and one product is set to Virtual (https://www.theartboxacademy.com/product/pediatric-hospital-boxes/). We're using Stripe as the payment method and for this product, they don't want the Shipping Address displayed, since there is no shipping address needed.

In Woo, that's not a problem using a function to hide the Shipping Address area. But if the customer uses Apple, Google or Amazon Pay, the modal that appears brings up a Shipping Address section,, even for virtual products.

Is there some way to hide this part for virtual products only?

Comment: You should need to ask plugin authors for stripe gateway, to see if there is an available hook for that, to remove the behavior from dedicated modal…

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a WooCommerce expert, but I believe you're seeing this because you set `wc_stripe_payment_request_params.product.requestShipping:true`. If you change this to false, then it shouldn't require the shipping address.

Comment: Where do you do that? Within Stripe's interface? Or Woo's?